# <body onload="function()"> makes my animatedImage stuck

Tags: .net, asp.net, html, visual-studio

I have a preload page with an animation.

```
<body onload="showSpinner()">
    <h3>Please Wait...</h3>
    <script>        
    function showSpinner() {
        showProgress();                      
        window.location.href = 'Report.aspx'; 
    }      
    </script>
</body>
```

When my function gets accessed and window.location.href fires, the animation freeze.  Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Is the spinner an animated gif, or is it animated using javascript?

Comment: What are the contents of `showProgress()`?

Comment: @JacobM - it is an animated gif.  @Rfvghn - Show progress is the code to display the animated gif.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to control the "freeze" in your animation.

The moment you are changing the location of the page, the browser fetches the new page and stops all processing of the current page, including animations. IIRC, this behaviour is not consistent across browsers.